# Запрос к таблице с перебором значений в цикле в PostgrSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица ObjectsHistory oh (прилагается).

Как сделать, чтобы из таблицы выбрать только те объекты, у которых в истории встречаются статусы ObjectStatus6, ObjectStatus7, ObjectStatus8 (каждый статус встречается как минимум 1 раз), причем хотя бы один из найденных статусов ObjectStatus8 по дате - позже, чем хотя бы один из найденных статусов ObjectStatus7 и хотя бы один из найденных статусов ObjectStatus7 по дате - позже, чем хотя бы один из найденных статусов ObjectStatus6.
Вывести ObjectsHistory oh полностью по выбранным объектам (лист Конечный результат).

[Ссылка на таблицу ObjectsHistory oh](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/p3NuLwwfyPCAJg)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Снимаю вопрос. Вопрос отпал.